# Easily renaming multiple tables in BigQuery. Is it possible?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got a bunch of tables in BigQuery that I'd like to rename. The primary reason for this is because I'd like to avail of the [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables) feature in my queries. The original format of my table names are not designed to work well with this feature.

Is it possible to programmatically/easily rename a lot of tables in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to rename a table in BigQuery. The way to achieve this is by running a BigQuery copy job that will copy the table with the new name, and when it's finished then delete the original table. Running copy jobs do not incur processing charges.

Using the `bq` command line tool, some simple bash would do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SRC="<project-id>:<dataset>"
bq ls --max_results=500 --format=csv $SRC | awk '{if(NR>1)print}' | awk -F, '{print $1}' | while read -r TABLE; do bq cp -f "${SRC}.${TABLE}" "${SRC}.${TABLE}_transformed_${RANDOM}" && bq rm -f "${SRC}.${TABLE}";done
```

**Warning**: this deletes the original table afterwards! Be careful.

One thing to note here is the `--max_results` parameter. This is important because by default the `bq ls` command only lists 50 tables in the dataset. So this parameter is needed to pull back all the tables in the dataset (adjust accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
RENAME TO mynewtable;
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#renaming-table